# Erro ao adicionar informações no BD

Tags: postgresql, delphi-7

Ao realizar testes na aplicação onde migrei o BD de Firebird para PostgreSQL o seguinte erro ocorre ao tentar salvar um item no banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Revisando o código pude ver que o erro ocorre na verdade neste ponto do código:

```
    dmCadMib.Consulta_Cliente(Cliente); // Nessa Linha pula para a procedure Consulta_Cliente
    dmCadMib.ConsClienteNoGrupo;
    dmCadMib.localizaCliente(StrToInt(Cliente));
Procedure Consulta_Cliente:

procedure TdmCadMIB.Consulta_Cliente(Codigo: string);

begin 
   cdsEmpresa.Close;
   sdsEmpresa.CommandText := 'select * from Empresa where Codigo =' + Codigo;
   cdsEmpresa.Open;
end;
```

Comment: Em qual dos dois inserts dá o erro? E você consegue depurar e colocar a `string` formada da forma que vai pro BD?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta @Sorack com o ponto correto onde o erro ocorre

Comment: Tá, mas coloca a string formada por isso, ou seja, o que vai efetivamente pro BD. É erro de sintaxe, dessa forma vai ficar extremamente simples de achar o erro

Comment: Cuidado com `cdsEmpresaNOME.AsString`, dependendo o que está nesta variável pode dar problema de sintaxe no SQL ou pior.  Ao invés disso, use [parâmetros](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A única coisa que pode estar errada é que a sua variável `Cliente` esta vazia ou nula. Mas aí tem que ver na regra de negócio onde deveria ser preenchida.

> syntax error at the end of the input

É um erro retornado pelo banco, sua `query` está sendo enviada como:

```
select * from Empresa where Codigo =;
```

Answer (score 4):

A Solução que encontrei foi converter a variável `codigo` para `integer` que era o formato que estava no banco:

a solução foi apenas isso: `procedure TdmCadMIB.Consulta_Cliente(Codigo: string);` alterei para `procedure TdmCadMIB.Consulta_Cliente(Codigo: Integer);`